# Sampling a proposed value with a limited range target when running MCMC

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, prior, metropolis-hastings, bounds, ergodic

I want to do an MCMC algorithm and need to sample a proposed value from a proposed distribution. In the Metropolis algorithm, people usually use a normal distribution as proposal. But if the prior distribution is a beta distribution. a realised value of a normal random variable may fall outside [0,1]. In such circumstances, how should we sample a value?

Comment: There is no need to adapt the proposal to the support of the target.If the proposed value has density zero, it is rejected.

Comment: you are right. But the acceptance rate will be so low.

Comment: @Xi'an So if I want to realize this algorithm, using R to unteract with Openbugs seems to be flexible but time consuming. It seems that MCMCpack in the R is more efficient. But I can only set normal prior distribution instead of the beta distribution I need. Is there any other package to use? If I write it by myself, the scale determing the proposed value each time  is difficult to set, it may result in the large unacceptance rate.

Comment: (i) the acceptance rate is high or low depending on the scale of the Normal; (ii) I have no advice to provide on a particular package.